# Accessing Ember Service from within Service Worker

Tags: ember.js, service-worker

For context, I'm attempting to implement Push Notifications using [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) and [Push Subscriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription).

I'm using [Ember Service Worker](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-service-worker) to help with adding Service Workers to an existing Ember project. This existing project already has a session service which handles maintaining user session information, and I would like access to that service from the context of the Service Worker(in order to map push subscriptions to users), however I can't seem to figure that out.